# Mysql: using case condition when selecting variable list from table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a large table and need to select some variables. First, this is the table structure:

```
gamecode---team---player---won

1---TeamA---TeamAPlayer1---1
1---TeamA---TeamAPlayer2---1
1---TeamA---TeamAPlayer3---1
1---TeamB---TeamBPlayer1---0
1---TeamB---TeamBPlayer2---0
2---TeamA---TeamAPlayer1---0
2---TeamA---TeamAPlayer2---0
2---TeamB---TeamBPlayer1---1
3---TeamC---TeamCPlayer1---0
3---TeamD---TeamDPlayer1---1
3---TeamD---TeamDPlayer2---1
4---TeamB---TeamBPlayer1---1
4---TeamD---TeamDPlayer1---0
```

That is, Won is a dummy variable that takes 1 if that team won the game, and 0 otherwise.

And now, my purpose: I want to count, grouping by team or by player the number of victories. I don't want to include that in the WHERE clause, but in the SELECT part, as the number of victories is only one among many others I want to collect with the same SELECT.

I tried this:

```
SELECT count(distinct gamecode*won) as victories FROM Mytable WHERE <conditions>
```

But with that select a team that lost all the games will count for 1 victory, since all gamecode*won will equal zero. And all teams winning and loosing some games will count one more victory that they have, as all games lost will result on a 'zero' value for gamecode*won variable.

What about including CASE in the SELECT, something like:

```
SELECT count(distinct case when gamecode*won is not 0 then 1 else 0 end) FROM Mytable WHERE <conditions>
```

Of course this does not work. Any suggestions? Thanks to everybody.

The expected result set would be, in case I group by team:

```
team---victories
TeamA---1
TeamB---2
TeamC---0
TeamD---1
```

That is, TeamA won only gamecode 1 and lost gamecode 2; TeamB won gamecode 2 and gamecode 4, while lost gamecode 1; TeamC won no game and lost gamecode 3; finally, TeamD won gamecode 3 and lost gamecode 4.

Comment: Have you looked at the `group by` function? You should be able to use that with the `where` clause to pull won games. Rough query `SELECT count(*) as victories, teamid FROM Mytable WHERE won = 1 group by teamid`

Comment: As I said, I don't want to include it in the WHERE clause, because I want to select many other variables for all the games, not only for games with won=1.

Comment: Rough query, you can modify the `group by` and what is in the `where`.

Comment: provide your expected resultset

Comment: Thank you Alex, now you have the expected result on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a6a3/2

This fiddle shows one way to do it.

The query is

```
select count(distinct (nullif(gamecode*won,0))) as victories, team from games group by team;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/048903/2

```
SELECT team, count(distinct (IF(won=1,gamecode, null))) as victories 
FROM Mytable 
GROUP BY team
```